# Using clFinish makes my code run faster

Tags: opencl

I have a code which is basically:

```
for (...) {
     clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...)
     clFinish(...)
     clEnqueueTask(...)
     clEnqueueReadBuffer(...) // blocking
}
```

Everything is on a single command queue and the out-of-order exec mode is not enabled.

This code runs in approximately 7.5s on my GPU hardware. Removing the clFinish call makes it run in 12s. I read that you need to call clFlush to start the execution of the queue, but replacing the clFinish with clFlush also make it run in 12s.

If I understood correctly, clFinish is a blocking call which waits for all commands to finish. How can using it instead of clFlush makes my code run faster?

Comment: Please provide the some more information about the hardware + driver you are using. If possible a small sample code too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm running this on an nVidia GTX 460 with the cuda driver. The code is from a bigger project, I can't put it here. To give a rough idea, the first kernel is what takes most of the time, the task is a one line kernel and the buffer I'm reading back is 17MB of floats.

Comment: Just produced a sample code [here](https://github.com/blastrock/A-Simple-OpenCL-C---Template)
This code runs in 26s for me, same if I uncomment the q.flush. It runs in 25s though if I uncomment the q.finish. I ran it a few times and got roughly the same results

Comment: As far as I have tested, it shouldn't have an impact on speed that clFInish().

Comment: Are you doing any kind of interoperability with OpenGL?

Comment: No, nothing opengl-related.

Answer (score 0):

calling clFinish prevents the the code from scheduling additional work items on the GPU. If you are scheduling more work items than the GPU can handle, then performance decreases. Without the code it's hard to say, but it sounds like that's your problem.